# Query for Insert into using values from other table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-insert

I have two tables Table1 ( with fields A1 | B1 | C1 ) and Table 2 with fields A2 | B2.

I need to insert into Table1 strokes with values A1 = const, B1 = const and C1 - value of A2 from Table2, where B2 = const

Table1

```
A1 | B1 | C1
```

Table 2

```
A2 | B2
1  | 3
2  | 3
6  | 3
4  | 6
5  | 6
```

After the query, where A1 = 0, B1 = 1, B2 = 3 we should get:

Table1

```
A1 | B1 | C1
0  | 1  | 1
0  | 1  | 2
0  | 1  | 6
```

I suppose that it will look like this:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (‘A1’,’B1’,’C1’) VALUES (0, 1, SELECT A2 FROM Table2 WHERE B2=”3”)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be looking for the standard [`INSERT ... SELECT` syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html):

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (A1, B1, C1) 
SELECT 0, 1, A2 FROM Table2 WHERE B2 = 3
```

Your original attempt does not work because `VALUES()` takes tuples of *scalar* values (each tuple represents one row), while the query returns *multiple rows*.